# Simple responsive content mobile/desktop with media query

Tags: html, css

```css
 /* Desktop */
 @media screen and (min-width:641px){ 
  .desktop{
  float: left;
  }
  .mobile{
  display: none;
  float: left;
  }
 }


 /* Mobile */
 @media screen and (max-width:641px){ 
  .desktop{
  display: none;
  float: left;
  }
  .mobile{
  float: left;
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="desktop">
    Show me on desktop
</div>
    
<div class="mobile">
    Show me on mobile
</div>
```

The simple code above displays some responsive content on my website.

When I run the code on the **desktop** I see both div containers:

```
Show me on desktop
Show me on mobile
```

Once I go the **mobile** size I only see the mobile content:

```
Show me on mobile
```

I want to achieve that on **desktop** the content is only:

```
Show me on desktop
```

What do I have to change in my code so only the `Show me on desktop` part is displayed on the **desktop**?

Comment: Works fine for me although there might be a chance that both show up at the same time when your window is 641px wide. So better set one as default (without a media query)

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: Unfortunately for me not, I tried both with firefox and edge.

Comment: Are you sure there's no other part of your code that could be affecting it?

Comment: Could be you are missing "<!DOCTYPE html>" ? Post your full html. Another reason could be some css override, or missing <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: Works fine for me but maybe get rid of the `min-width` media query used for desktop and make those properties default.

Comment: Guys, you seem about right. I just deleted all the other CSS and it worked. I have to check which CSS affects the whole thing.

Comment: Chrome 59 no repo

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `@media handheld and (max-width: 641px)` instant of `@media screen and (max-width: 641px)`, because it is no screen on a mobile device for css.
For more information take a look at:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp
Hope it helps.